# How to fetch files from CDN with NuxtJS content module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to fetch files from another server (e.g. a CDN) with the @nuxtjs/content module so that the .md files can be managed independently without Nuxt.js.

My current `nuxt.config.js` file looks like this:

```js
export default {
  ...
  content: {
    dir: 'http://some-cdn.xyz/content/'
  },
  ...
}
```

Now I want to load the content in the pages/_slug.vue file:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtContent :document="doc" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const doc = await $content(params.slug || 'index').fetch();
    return { doc };
  },
};
</script>
```

Now when I type in http://localhost:3000/some-page, I should get the corresponding file (some-page.md) from the CDN. Instead, I get this error from Nuxt.js: /some-page not found.

What should I do to get it working and is this even possible with my current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told here: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/237

This is not doable with the `content` module and is not planned to be done neither. A solution would be to manually fetch the files during the build time or alike.

You can maybe get some inspiration from this comment: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/37#issuecomment-664331854 or use another markdown parser.

Answer (score 1):

Since @nuxtjs/content can't fetch files from another server, I used the [marked.js](https://marked.js.org/) library instead.